# What is meant by collapse of wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, wave-particle-duality, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

Collapse of wave function ,does it really happens?why?

Comment: There is no spoon...

Comment: This is a hard question, about which whole books have been written. Have you poked around wikipedia for any relevant entries? recommend you have a look and then come back here if there's anything remaining that still puzzles you. -NN

Comment: No. Collapse doesn't happen. Read "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch chapter 2.

Answer (score 2):

Schlosshauer reviewed experimental data and concluded: "no positive experimental evidence exists for physical state-vector collapse"
(Annals of Physics, 321 (2006) 112-149)

Comment: The notion of a wave function collapsing isn't a dynamical thing that is an observable though

Comment: @InertialObserver : The OP asks if collapse of wave function really happens, and my answer is there is no experimental evidence of that.

Comment: Something happens though whether you call it a "collapse" or not. It is an easily observable effect, e.g. in a double slit experiment. There was a wave and now it is no more. Sounds evidence enough, no?

Comment: @safesphere : No, there is no experimental evidence of deviations from unitary evolution. From the same article: "the universal validity of unitary dynamics and the superposition principle has been confirmed far into the mesoscopic and macroscopic realm in all experiments conducted thus far"

Comment: Well, I hear you, but I didn't say anything about "unitary evolution". It seems that you are assuming that I've implied this and that in my comment, but I really haven't. All I'm saying, it is easily observable that a wave is killed by measurement. This is an experimental fact. The wave was there, but no more. You can call it "collapse" or "murder", whatever, but the wave is destroyed.

Comment: @safesphere : Your phrase "a wave is killed by measurement" seems to mean that unitary evolution does not describe the act of measurement correctly. Unitary evolution does not describe any "wave killing".

Comment: I think what @safesphere is saying is that *something* happens. It seems like you both are just differing in what you define as a "collpase". Safesphere recognizes this, but you do not.

Comment: @AaronStevens : If safesphere uses some homegrown definition of collapse, (s)he should have mentioned that.

Comment: They did mention what they were considering to be a collapse. And I don't think it is "homegrown" at all. You are choosing to talk about collapse in a particular way. We are talking about collpase in general.

Comment: @AaronStevens : As far as I can see, safesphere defines collapse as "The wave was there, but no more" (with some variations). And, as I said, this contradicts unitary evolution, and there is no experimental evidence of violations of unitary evolution. If you find a different definition of collapse in safesphere's comments, please let me know.